# Objective C: calculator app - currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + digit;

Tags: objective-c, xcode, calculator

I am reading "Programming in Objective-C" 4th Ed. by Stephen G. Kochan. In the book, there is a sample code for creating a Calculator application for the iPhone. I understand the code, at least 90% of it. - There is a Fraction class that has methods to store fraction objects and that describe how to perform different basic fraction arithmetic operations
- In addition to that, there is a calculator class that runs the appropriate methods from the Fraction class depending on whether the user is trying to sum, divide etc.

The view controller has the following method for when the user presses a number in the interface:

```
-(IBAction)clickDigit:(UIButton *)sender {
int digit = sender.tag;     //sender or the argument inthis case is  the button

[self processDigit:digit];
}
```

As you see this method is now called:

```
-(void) processDigit:(int)digit {
currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + digit;

[displayString appendString:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", digit]];
display.text = displayString;

}
```

My ONLY question (and probably the one with the most simple answer) is: Why is currentNumber always multiplied by 10? The value of currentNumber is always 0 by the time the compiler enters the method above (I verified this using the debugger in XCode) so i dont get why we even have to multiply it by 10. I did delete that multiplication and the results are incorrect, i just cannot figure out why yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best way to think about this is with an example.

Imagine the user has clicked the following digits in order:  1, 2.  Then, assuming the code is working, the numeric value of `currentNumber` should be 12.

Now imagine the user next clicks on '3'.  Now you want the value to be 123.  You can get this by multiplying the previous value (12) by 10 and then adding the 3.  If they then click on a '4', the value should become 1,234, which is achieved by 10 * 123 + 4.  And so on.

Comment: Nice! I get it now. Thanks a lot. My brain was thinking that those methods only get called once for the numerator and once for the denominator. I did not think about the limitiation of using integers instead of strings and was forgetting about the fact that the methods actually get called for every digit that gets pressed, not just once for for the denominator and once for the numerator of each operand.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your calculator has "123" on the screen and you want to turn this into "1234". If it was a string you can add "4" to the end, and it works fine. But it's an integer, and if you add 4 to the integer value you get 127. So what you do is take 123, multiply by 10 to give you 1230, then add the 4 to get 1234.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger must be misleading you, as it sometimes does.

Consider that if taking the multiplication out makes the result wrong then the multiplication obviously does something!

Try the following for debugging only:

```
int lastCurrentNumber = currentNumber;
currentNumber = 10 * lastCurrentNumber + digit;
```

Now in the debugger check the values of `lastCurrentNumber`, `currentNumber` and `digit` as you step through these two statements.

Comment: I was actually forgetting about the limitiation of using integers instead of strings and was forgetting about the fact that the methods actually get called for every digit that gets pressed, not just once for for the denominator and once for the numerator of each operand. When testing with the debugger. I must have entered only single digit numerators and denominators when testing this initially (which I realize was a dumb mistake from my part). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `*10` is used to move digits through the various places in decimal numbers (tens place, hundreds place, etc.)

It's kind of a "hack" to avoid having to use an array.  Other calculator apps "pop" and "push" digits onto an array, this allows for more powerful operations as well as manipulation of non-decimal numbers (binary, hex, etc.)

The free iOS development course on iTunes U includes a calculator app that uses an array.  If you'd like to compare the difference, you can download the source code here:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/

It also has a Fraction object but doesn't use the `*10` method.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now and also realized I was not testing this enough. I also forgot about the iTunes U videos which I will be checking out soon.